# IceMegaMenu dropdown on mobile

Tags: menu, joomla-3.7, dropdown

I am using iceMegaMenu and dropdown menu features.

I have a one dropdown, which is working fine, but I have a problem with displaying it on mobile phones.

It's by default expanded, but I want to hide it and only show it by clicking on the arrow. Everything is default and I didn't edit anything in the menu code.

I thought it should be feature available in options, but there's nothing like this in there.

I am using joomla 3.7.0.

TLDR : Menu is showed by default. I want it to be hidden and only expanded when I click on the arrow.

[image]